GEE function to apply annual reducer for multiple years in image collection
I'm working with a GEE image collection that includes multiple images for each year
var studyRegion = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Rwanda"));

var DW = ee.ImageCollection("GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1")
  .filterBounds(studyRegion).select("label");

Data are available 2016-2023. I want to get a modal reduction for each region. Without a function I have to do a lot of copy-paste:

var DW_2016 = DW.filterDate("2016-06-01", "2016-08-31")
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mode()).clip(studyRegion);


I am trying to find a function in which I define the year and the function generates the modal reduction for that year. I've searched for past answers to this problem but could not find any, and I mostly find (in tutorials, etc.) that people do these reductions separately for each year. A function-based approach would reduce the likelihood of human error.

If you have multiple study regions, then you can combine their geometries into a single feature collection as given here. Then you can clip your image or image collections to each feature in the feature collection.
As for a function to pass the year as an argument, have a look at the function named yearly_filter:
var studyRegion = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Rwanda"));

var DW = ee.ImageCollection("GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1")
  .filterBounds(studyRegion).select("label");
  
  
var DW_2016 = DW.filterDate("2016-06-01", "2016-08-31")
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mode()).clip(studyRegion);


function yearly_filter(year){
  
  var modal_image = DW
       .filterDate(year.toString()+'-06-01',year.toString()+'-08-31')
       .reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());
  
  return modal_image
  
}


/* Following print function will give you the modal reduction 
of all images from '2019-06-01' to '2019-08-31' */

print(yearly_filter(2019))


